# Hibernate exception during order by with HashSet on HQL query: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query using scroll

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hashset

I'm trying to get a list of items ordered through an **HQL query**. The problem is that the sort is done on a HashSet of objects(orber by ab.clienti.errIndirizzos, where **errIndirizzos** is **HashSet** set on class `Clienti`), and when I try to do the sorting hibernate returns an exception

**Clienti.java:**

```
public class Cliente implements java.io.Serializable {
//declaration var
private Set errIndirizzos = new HashSet(0);`
.....
}
```

**Cliente.hbm.xml**

```
<set name="errIndirizzos" inverse="true" >
     <key>
         <column name="ID_CLIENTE" precision="18" scale="0" />
     </key>
     <one-to-many class="ErrIndirizzo" />
</set>
```

where table ERR_INDIRIZZO and CLIENTE have unique key `"ID_CLIENTE"`

**HQL Query order by:**

```
order by le.cliente.errIndirizzos
```

where `le` is another table that contain Clienti

**LetteraCliente.java**

```
public class Letteracliente implements java.io.Serializable {
.....
private Cliente cliente
......
}
```

**letteraCliente.hbm.xml**

```
<one-to-one name="cliente" class="it.allianz.images.bean.postaMassiva.Cliente" constrained="true"></one-to-one>
```

**Error:**

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query using scroll
```

Any suggestion? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the full HQL you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try using implicit joins instead:

```
select distinct le
from Letteracliente le
inner join le.cliente c
inner join c.errIndirizzos e
order by e.id
```

Using INNER JOIN will also filter all `Letteracliente` without `Cliente` or `ErrIndirizzo`.
You can choose some other property for the ORDER BY, if the `id` is not what you wanted.